# Uploadify works when change database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, uploadify

I'm using uplodify with CodeIgniter.

I have 2 database settings. One is from localhost another one is from http://phpmyadmin.co.

If I select database as phpmyadmin.co server uploading is working fine. But if I select my localhost database then then uploadify returns http 500 error or IO error.

But the file is uploaded successfully to the folder but always return onUploadError function

Using the following code to upload

```
$(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'formData'     : {
                    'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                    'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
                    'wallmount_id' : $('#id').val(),
                    'sessionID' : '<?php echo session_id(); ?>', 
                    'user' : '1'
                },
                'swf'      : './uploadify.swf',
                'uploader' : 'home/save_video',
                'fileTypeDesc' : 'Video Files',
                'fileTypeExts' : '*.mp4; *.avi; *.webm; *.3gp; *.mov; *.mpeg; *.3gp; *.wmv',
                'auto' : false,
                'buttonText': 'Select Video File',
                'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
                    $("#file_upload").uploadify("settings", "formData", {'id' : $('#id').val()});
                },
                'onUploadSuccess' : function(file,data,response) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
                 alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
        }
        });


    });
```

And this is controller function to save uploaded file

```
public function save_video() {

        $verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

        if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {

            $config = set_upload_options('uploads/videos');
            $this->load->library('upload');


            $new_name = $_POST['id']."_".time()."_".$_FILES["Filedata"]['name'];
            $config['file_name'] = $new_name;
            $this->upload->initialize($config);



            //$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
            $targetFile = 'uploads/videos/'.$new_name;
                //$this->upload->do_upload('Filedata');
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload("Filedata")){

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', array('message' => $this->upload->display_errors(), 'title' => 'Error !', 'class' => 'danger'));
                }   
                else {
                    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                    $data['video_path'] = 'uploads/videos/'.$file_name;
                    $result = $this->home->save_videos($data);

                }   


        }
    }
```

and my model code is

```
function save_videos($data) {
     $result = $this->db->insert('videos', $data); 

     if($result) {
         return $this->db->insert_id();
     }
     else {
         return false;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the controller and model file code ?

Comment: @VairaMuthu added controller and model code too

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query(); check the insert or not in video table ?

Comment: not inserted and nothing returns

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: On display error in php.ini and check your error

Comment: @VairaMuthu nothing returns

Comment: which code after display 500 internal error ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102326/discussion-between-vaira-muthu-and-ragu).